# Sprint Boot Junit5 Test fails to run

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, junit5

I had a test to test access to db in a spring boot app, which was written for Junit 4.
I changed this test to Junit 5. With the following additions to my pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>funnel-backend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>funnel-backend</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.5.2</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.5.2</junit.platform.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The test itself is fairly simple

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class UserDataTest {

    @Autowired
    UserDataRepository repository;

    @Test
    void testAddAnswers() {
        UserData data = new UserFunnelData(1L);
        data.addData("SomeData",true);
        repository.save(data);

        Optional<UserData>  lookup = repository.findById(1L);
        assertTrue(lookup.isPresent());
        assertEquals("SomeData", lookup.get().getData());
        repository.deleteById(1L);//Cleaning up.
    }
 }
```

When I try and run this intellij, i don't see anything on the console. Just the message poping up "Failed to run". I know this isn't a lot to go on. I would appreciate any pointers or suggestions on how to attack this.

Comment: You can remove `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`, this is already part of `@SpringBootTest`. If you just want to test a repository, you can use `@DataJpaTest` instead of `@SpringBootTest`. The advantage is that you don't need to clean up your data for such tests manually. Can you try running `mvn test` from the command line to see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

You have spring boot 2.5, which already includes jupiter. The exclusions of junit that you have in your pom file is required for older versions.

Most developers use the spring-boot-starter-test “Starter”, which imports both Spring Boot test modules as well as JUnit Jupiter, AssertJ, Hamcrest, and a number of other useful libraries.

If you have tests that use JUnit 4, JUnit 5’s vintage engine can be used to run them. To use the vintage engine, add a dependency on junit-vintage-engine, as shown in the following example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

[source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing)